# RichTextBox.Select(0,1) configures whole text

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the codesnippet:

```
  richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
  richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
```

after this part is executed the first symbol of the text is selected, but the whole code is formated.

Here's the whole methode:

Where `proccesses` is a `List<System.Diagnostics.Proccess>`

and `knownProcesses` is a `List<ProccessData>`

`ProcessData` is a "datawrapper" I wrote

```
    void updateRTB1()
    {
        string text = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (ProcessData pd in knownProcesses)
            {
                if (pd.resembles(processes[i]))
                {
                    text += pd.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

            text += "\n";
        }

        richTextBox1.Text = text;

        richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
    }
```

The methode is called once in the constructor of the containing Form.
That is the only time I use it so far.

Thank you for your help

```
  richTextBox1.Select(1, 1);
  richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
```

works fine btw.

Comment: If this is called more than once then you'll get what you describe.  Since you didn't restore the selection colors.

Comment: as i said i only call updateRTB1() once in the constructor of the form